# I can't detect multiple files with different types selected in html5

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code,

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][0]) && isset($_FILES['file']['name'][1])){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "2";
}
```

It returns 2.

Here is my HTML code,

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

I read on other tutorials and still cannot detect if the files are set.
How can I detect the files that are set? My files are at MP3, and Docx format.

Comment: close: `$_FILES['file'][0]['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You can first use var_dump and see the $_FILES variable

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

For check isset you can use this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'][0]['tmp_name'])){
   echo "ok";
else
  echo "error";
?>
```

And you can use this code to get array from $_FILES and save it

```
<?php
 foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file){
   var_dump($files);
 }
?>
```

After see the result you can use move_uploaded_file to copy temp file to your directory for example

```
<?php
 foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file){
   move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],'/your/save/path');
 }
?>
```

**Read the following link**

[move uploaded file - php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples)

Answer (score -1):

"How can I detect the files that are set?" -- What do you mean by this, if any file has been uploaded at all ? Check the errors first. This may help: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php